# Change button image for the rest of the app usage

Tags: ios, uibutton, uiimage

I'm trying to build an app with Twitter integration. When the user clicks on a share button, this button should change its image. This already works but when the user clicks through other views and finally again clicks on the view with the share button...the image is the old one again. I don't know how to fix this so I help you can give me some advice :)
Here`s the code:

in my .h file:

```
- (IBAction)postToTwitter:(id)sender;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *tweetBTN;
```

...and in my .m file:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
//some code here
   if ([[UIImage imageNamed:@"twitter02_dark.png"] isEqual:_tweetBTN.currentImage]) {
       UIImage *twitterImage2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"twitter02_active.png"];
       [_tweetBTN setImage:twitterImage2 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   }
   else {
       UIImage *twitterImage1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"twitter02_active.png"];
       [_tweetBTN setImage:twitterImage1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   }

}





  - (IBAction)postToTwitter:(id)sender {       
        if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter])
        {
            SLComposeViewController *tweetSheet = [SLComposeViewController          
composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];
            //some code here
            UIImage *twitterImage2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"twitter02_dark.png"];
            [_tweetBTN setImage:twitterImage2 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
    }
```

It would be great if someone could help me...

***UPDATE:***
I modified like in the answer...but I don`t get one thing: after first launching the app the image should be active (because it isn`t "tweeted")...

```
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"tweeted"]) {
        UIImage *twitterImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"twitter02_dark.png"];
        [_tweetBTN setImage:twitterImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else {
        UIImage *twitterImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"twitter02_active.png"];
        [_tweetBTN setImage:twitterImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
```

...but the image is dark...why? Afterwards this if-method works normally...very strange to me

Comment: Do you not want to hold a flag to remember the state rather than use an image in a view and trying to compare equality ?

Comment: That would be an alternative, but I do not know how to program this.

Comment: Now it finally works...don`t know why...but I`m happy ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try using user defaults to store the fact that the button has been pressed

in your postToTwitter method:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"tweeted"];
```

and get rid of the statement in you viewDidLoad, and put this in viewDidAppear:

```
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"tweeted"]) {
   UIImage *twitterImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"twitter02_dark.png"];
   [_tweetBTN setImage:twitterImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
else {
   UIImage *twitterImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"twitter02_active.png"];
   [_tweetBTN setImage:twitterImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

this will persist between app launches, so if you quit the app and then go back in, the button will still be dark

Comment: Hm...this only works when I switch between the tabs in the tabbar...but after clicking through the other views, the image is the old one again

Comment: not sure what you mean... you still need to update the image in the postToTwitter method as well of course.. (like you were before)

Comment: ah, i see - another thing to do in that case is move the code in viewDidLoad to viewWillAppear instead. that way it will get set every time the view appears, not just when the app first loads

Comment: are you wanting it to go back to the "active" image when you go away from the view then come back? can you explain more clearly what the problem is?

Comment: ok: at first the image is active, after you click it it is dark...and it still should be dark when you come back...but instead of being still dark it`s active again

Comment: ok, we shouldn't get into debugging in the comments section.. but i think i just got the active and dark buttons the wrong way round in the code i wrote above? try switching them around. just read what the code is saying: "if tweeted, show this image, otherwise, show this one" - just make sure they're the way round you want them to be! i'll edit the answer above